# Hover state with line-height

Tags: html, css, hover

My problem is with hover state of this [pen](http://codepen.io/aktuna/pen/pxcBy):

I need to center vertically the marquee but, when i use `line-height` , the hover state doesn't respond or sometimes tickles, and I don't want to use `top` property,  either.

Comment: What browser support do you need

Comment: every browser if possible, but firstly chrome and firefox

Comment: And why do you want to avoid `top`?

Comment: Same thing happens with top property, when i hover to the center of arrow. It doesn't respond. please check this [pen](http://codepen.io/aktuna/pen/GuFBf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div class="kayan">Contacts</div>` is overlaping `<div class="right_del"></div>`, so hover event is never thrown. Add `z-index:2` css property to `.right_del`.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVzbQ/)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the corrected [pen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hwGpj)